# How to know which method is not implemented for C2259 VS 2017 error?

Tags: c++, com, visual-studio-2017, iunknown

I am defining a new interface and a class that implements it. I have added my class(XXX) and interface(IXXX) in idl file (I generated two uuids). My interface has two simple methods. I have implemented them( files XXX.h and XXX.cpp). I included the following line in InprocServer.cpp.

```
UNKNOWN_OBJECT(XXX)
```

I am getting the following error:
Error   C2259   'XXX': cannot instantiate abstract class (compiling source file InprocServer.cpp)
clicking on error takes me to the following line in

```
Unknown.h
      try
      {
        **p = new T(pUnkOuter);  // refcount is already 1**
        if (!p)
          return E_OUTOFMEMORY;
      }
```

How do I know which method is not implemented?

Comment: The build log command line output is usually helpful, and often includes a list of useful list of footnotes when an error is encountered (in the Output window with Build selected, not the Error List)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the output window (View->Output)rather than the error list and any unimplemented members will be part of the diagnostic.

This works so long as you have the setting in Tools->Options, Projects and Solutions->Build and Run for MSBuild verbosity set to at least 'Minimal', I'm not sure about 'Quiet'.

Comment: Also, familiarise yourself with the `override` keyword and use it in your derived class. That will catch any typos.